# how to display map in mobile devices using magnific popup?

Tags: magnific-popup

i have magnific popup plugin to show map on the popup but its not working properly in mobile devices.
if i click on that it redirecting to google map page

Here my code

```js
$('.video, .map-link').magnificPopup({
   type: 'iframe',
   mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
   removalDelay: 160,
   preloader: false,
   fixedContentPos: false
});
```

Comment: please provide the .video .map-link  div codes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```js
 $('.video, .map-link').magnificPopup({
     type: 'iframe',
     mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
     removalDelay: 160,
     preloader: false,
     fixedContentPos: false,
     iframe: {
         markup: '<div class="mfp-iframe-scaler">'+
                 '<div class="mfp-close"></div>'+
                 '<iframe class="mfp-iframe" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'+
                 '</div>', 
         patterns: {
             gmaps: {
                 index: '//maps.google.',
                 src: '%id%&output=embed'
             }
         },
         srcAction: 'iframe_src', 
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

colares's solution worked for me. I also added a media query since the popup on mobile was a narrow rectangle, this makes it wider:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 875px) {.mfp-container {  
height: 90%;
width: 175%;  
left: -37%; }}
```